# Trying to make a right-only border for a linearlayout in android; however the rectangle is all black

Tags: android, user-interface, border, drawable

Hey guys I have this code for a border:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="-10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/transparent">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#191A18" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and I wanted a border that would be transparent everywhere else except it would have a bar on the right most edge.

However instead what I get is a huge black rectangle which fills the linear layout...

Comment: Try getting rid of the stuff defined under item, and add `android:gravity="right"` to your shape object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ff000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```